# How to remove minted indentation level with correct latex indentation?

Tags: indentation, minted, source

When writing with minted code snippets I dislike to remove indentation in latex source, so correct results are generated. Is there a way to substract latex indentation-level from minted indentation? I hope this mwe makes it clear:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{minted}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
  \begin{itemize}
    \item readable Latex source

      \begin{minted}{python}
        l = 1
      \end{minted}

      not so nice Latex source but, correct indentation

      \begin{minted}{python}
l = 1        
      \end{minted}

      So how to subtract the indentation level from latex source?

  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

producing this output:
[image]

BTW: Please consider that code listings may have a line lengths up to 80 characters, where this additional indent will cause overlapping source, or linebreaks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's an option called `autogobble` which does exactly what you want.

[image: autogobble]

```
% arara: pdflatex: {shell: 1}
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{minted}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
  \begin{itemize}
    \item readable Latex source

      \begin{minted}[autogobble]{python}
        l = 1
      \end{minted}

      not so nice Latex source but, correct indentation

      \begin{minted}{python}
l = 1        
      \end{minted}

      So how to subtract the indentation level from latex source?

  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

This has been long answered but I wanted to further add that the command `\noindent` works perfectly well within normal text. I'm not sure if it does within your code but it's worth keeping the idea in mind anyway.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).