# Minted package does not recognize lexer inside listing

Tags: minted, sourcecode

I have a problem with the minted package. I am using two different lexers, `julia`and `jlcon`. The first one properly highlights code, but the second one only works if the code is not inside a `listing`environment?

I have no idea why this is the case.

An example is the following:

This doesnt work:

```
\begin{listing}[H]
    \caption{bla bla bla}
    \label{----}
    \begin{minted}{jlcon}

    julia> E = some_fun()


    julia> gen = point(E)
    Output 3213

    julia> orden = order(gen)
    15289

    julia> 
    \end{minted}
\end{listing}
```

However, if you remove the `\listing` environment it works properly.

Comment: Removing the indentation fixes the problem for some reason.

Comment: I'm guessing it is looking for the explicit string `\end{minted}` from the start of løthe line. Btw: please always post full but minimal examples, then others can test your code as is. For example I don't know whether the listing env need an extra unknown package.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/447465/how-to-remove-minted-indentation-level-with-correct-latex-indentation